# Loading só aparece depois da página carregada

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma página com um menu lateral, e o conteúdo desse menu é aberto dentro de um iframe.

CSS

```
#preloader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

ALBUM.PHP

```
<body>
  <div id="preloader"><img src="images/loading_azul.gif"></div>
    <div id="conteudo">
      ...
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Esconde preloader
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#preloader').fadeOut(1500); //1500 é a duração do efeito (1.5 seg)
    });
});
```

O problema é que só no final desse carregamento, ele mostra a animação do gif na tela, um pouco antes de ocultar.

[LINK](http://www.fertrilhos.com.br/mg/teste/)

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque?

Comment: O que faz a função `carregando()`? E onde está o HTML `#carregando` e `#loading`?

Comment: O Html é esse: <div id="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif"></div>

Comment: Ok, e onde está ele? dentro do menu? iframe? Pode colocar o HTML completo? assim vamos estar a adivinhar...

Comment: Ele está dentro da página album.php, que abre dentro do iframe, só não posto ela porque tem muitas linhas...

Comment: @Sergio editei a pergunta, veja se ficou mais claro.. Vlw!

Comment: Ficou ainda menos claro :) Então tem uma div `<div id="conteudo">` que tem o mesmo ID que a iFrame? `<iframe id="conteudo"... `

Comment: Não tinha visto que estavam com o mesmo nome, pode ser por isso?

Comment: Pode ser. As IDs têm de ser únicas. Se não fôr isso preciso ainda de mais código para ajudar. JS e HTML...

Comment: Blz, vou alterar e verificar se funfa. Senão a noite tento mandar mais detalhes... Vlw por enquanto!

Comment: @Sergio, editei a pergunta e coloquei o link para poder visualizar o que está acontecendo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19323/discussion-between-ricardo-and-sergio).

Comment: Ricardo, está funcionando no InternetExplorer, mas só faltou setar uma altura melhor. Ele faz o que você está qurendo. Teste nos outros navegadores.

Comment: Rafael, é verdade eu estava vendo apenas no Firefox. No Chrome parece que tá redondo tb... Vou mudar a altura sim, pode deixar! Vlw

Answer (score 2):

Ele só aparece pois você está carregando a página como um todo dentro de um iframe.

Ou seja, o gif só é carregado após a requisição terminar.
Para resolver isso você tem que retirar esse gif da página de dentro do iframe e colocar no escopo da página que possui o menu.

E ainda por cima podia parar de usar iframe e usar pelo menos ajax para requisitar o conteúdo do iframe.

um simples $("div").load("url") resolveria o seu problema.

E então você poderia definir o aparecimento e desaparecimento do seu gif com um ajaxComplete e ajaxStart.

```
$( "meuMenu" ).click(function() {
   $( "suaDiv" ).load( "ajax/suapagina.html" );
});
```

em vez de iframe vc colocaria uma div e passaria a url que queria carregar nela para o método load do jquery.

e para mostrar e esconder o seu loading na hora certa

```
$.ajaxStart(function(){
    $('seuGif').show();
});

$.ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('seuGif').hide();
});
```

quando ocorrer um evento ajax na sua página, no caso o $.load, como eu exemplifiquei acima, o ajaxStart vai ser chamado, e quando a página terminar de carregar pelo ajax o ajaxComplete vai ser chamado escondendo o seu gif.